# Go to related records not working as expected

Tags: filemaker

I'm having an issue with "Go to related record" script where it's not taking me to the expected set of records.

I have two tables: `agendas` and `items`. `Agendas` can have multiple `items` and `items` can exist on multiple `agendas`. So to support this I created a third table, `AgendaItems`.

I have two layouts: Agendas (plural) and Agenda (singular). Apologies for the very similar names.

Agendas (plural) is a list-view that displays every agenda as a row. When I click on an agenda I use "Go to related records" to navigate to the Agenda (singular) layout and show only the items for that specific agenda.

[image]

Agenda (singular) is a form-view based on the Item table. It contains a portal that displays all items on the agenda. When I click on an item in the portal it shows me the details of that specific item. I'm using a cartesian join to an instance of the AgendaItem's table to accomplish this.

[image]

Everything was working great until I tried to put a single `Item` on multiple `Agendas`. When I create a second `AgendaItem` record for an `Item` the "Go to related records" script stops working as expected.

Specifically, when I try to navigate from Agendas (plural) to Agenda (singular) it takes me to the same set of records each time.

For example, if I click on Agenda A I see items related to Agenda A. But when I click on Agenda B I also see items for Agenda A. If I delete the `AgendaItem` record that is pointing to an `Item` for the second time it works again.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Well, without seing the file, it's hard to pinpoint it excactly, but be careful using a cartesian join with join tables. Regardless of any filter you have in the portal, a cartesian join always resolve to the complete record set in the foreign table.

Comment: That must be the problem. If I change the join type to "=" it shows the first related record of the set, but only one record. Any idea how I might solve this?

Comment: Switch off any filtering you may have active. Any reason why you don't use the AgendaItem TO for your portal?

Comment: What do you mean AgendaItem TO?

Comment: TO = Table Occurence

Comment: Ah, yeah I might as well use the AgendaItem TO if I don't need the cartesian join. I turned off filtering and it still only displays one item.

Comment: How many Agendaitems do you have with this Item ID? Do a search and compare.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160218/discussion-between-colindunn-and-andreast).

Answer (score 0):

> Agenda (singular) is a form-view based on the Item table. It contains a portal that displays all items on the agenda.

The "Agenda" layout should be based on the Agendas TO. Display the related Items using a portal based on the AgendaItems TO.

To view the related Item record, do it in two steps:

```
Go to Related Records [ AgendaItems ; current record ]
Go to Related Records [ Items ; found set ]
```

The first GTRR selects the related AgendaItems records and changes to a layout based on the AgendaItems TO. The second GTRR finds the Items records related to the current found set of AgendaItems records, and changes to a layout based on the Items TO.

BTW if filtering is used to control the display of records in the AgendaItems portal on the Agendas form layout, you can do some processing in-between the two GTRR steps to omit the join records that aren't displayed...

```
go to related records [ AgendaItems ; current record ]

go to record/request [ first ]

loop
 exit loop if [ get( found count ) = 0 ]
 if [ <portal_filter_expression> = 1 ]
  go to record/request [ next ; exit after last ]
 else
  omit record/request
 end if
end loop

if [ get( found count ) = 0 ]
 go to layout [ original layout ]
 show custom dialog [ "There are no items to display." ] 
 exit script
end if

go to related records [ Items ; found set ]
```